# neo4j cypher, find node and it is relation by id

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I want match node by node id and also get it is relation to another node, 
first part is work, when you pass params, but I do not know how to get relation between another node and return also second node properties.

This part is work :

```
MATCH (a:Player) where ID(a)= {id} RETURN ID(a), a.name, a.surname, a.position
```

This is full query :

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("id", id);
ExecutionResult result = engine.execute("MATCH (a:Player) where ID(a)= {id}- [:`PLAY_IN`]-(b:Team) "
        + " RETURN ID(a), a.name, a.surname, a.position, ID(b), b.name ", params);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I read your cypher correctly, you want:

```
MATCH (a)-[:PLAY_IN]-(b:Team)
WHERE ID(a) = {id}
RETURN ID(a), a.name, a.surname, a.position, ID(b), b.name
```

I am not totally sure on the syntax for using parameters here, but you have the WHERE in the wrong place. You could also do:

```
MATCH (a)
WHERE ID(a) = {id}
MATCH (a)-[:PLAY_IN]-(b:Team)
RETURN ID(a), a.name, a.surname, a.position, ID(b), b.name
```

But basically a where ends the match clause, and you need to start a new Match clause.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answers, it is very useful for me, it works, I tried to understand cypher. I think this will be helpfull also for another people.

Comment: No problem. I also use these boards for Cypher Help.

Comment: @ArmenArzumanyan If you think the answer is correct and helpful you can "accept" it. This gives some extra credit to the person who helped you and it also shows that the question has a correct answer to other people who are searching on SO.